# Difficuluty onAreaTouched ANd onscreenTOuched

Tags: android, andengine

I got a problem in my simple game.

I got onscreentouch  to move the player and i have a  aon areatouched button for firing.
The problem is that if i am moving, i can't fire.
Why??

Thanks

Comment: Add some code to the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Do you enable the multi-touch function in your EngineOption?

```
engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);
```